# How can I upload a picture in a server using Android and Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to upload a picture in a server with Retrofit but I get HTTP 400 error. I know that this error mean that the call has not been done correctly but I do dont know when I am doing wrong. I only need to upload a single image.

I have tried adding headers multipart/form-data and also content-type: image/jpeg and also without but it keeps throwing 400 error.

This code in the interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("https://myweb.com/endpoint")
Observable<DefaultResponse> uploadUserImageRx(
    @Part MultipartBody.Part image
);
```

And here the call:

```
var file = // initialized file here

var filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.getName(),   RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file))

unsubscribeUploadPhoto()
uploadPhotoSubscription = MyApiClient.getApi()
    .uploadUserImageRx(filePart)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(object : SubscriberAdapter<DefaultResponse>() 
        {
          //Notify everything went well.
        })
```

I expect the photo to be upload but i get this error instead.

The requirements of the endpoint are:

Authorization(header) as String

Comment: did you try this with postman ? is it work in postman

Comment: @Dulanga I have tried but with same parameters. I guess I am missing any requirements in header or in the call. API ask for Authorization in header but I dont know how to add it.

Comment: please check below my answer and when you call login request you will receive access token and pass it as Authorization  in this api

Answer (score 0):

This error mean that you didn,t attached headers correctly as I think there should be a header like  access token. check if there is something like that  then implement your API like below.

```
@Multipart
@POST("https://myweb.com/endpoint")
Observable<DefaultResponse> uploadUserImageRx(
    @Header("Authorization") String authorization,  
    @Part MultipartBody.Part image
);
```